# Iterating through a variable line by line

Tags: powershell

I have a small script that outputs text into a variable.
I need to go through it line by one in order to parse it.
I could do this by outputting the variable to a text file and then reading it using Get-Content but that seems a bit redundant.

My script connects to a Fortigate unit and runs a certain query. It's response is what I'm looking to parse.

```
New-SshSession 10.0.0.138 -Port 65432 -Credential (Get-Credential) -AcceptKey
$command = 'config router policy
show'
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command $command
```

Comment: Why was I voted down?
This cannot be found anywhere on Stackoverflow...

Comment: If your variable is already an `[Object[]]`, iterate right now. If not, use `split`.

Comment: And about downvotes, they probably say you've not searched hard enough. Probably provide code about how do you get the variable's contents, XXXXing the sensitive data if there's any.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By your description, your variable is a string with newlines. You can turn it into an array of single-line string by calling this:

```
$result = $result -split "`r`n"
```

Answer (score 25):

```
ForEach ($line in $($result -split "`r`n"))
{
    Write-host $Line
}
```

Comment: The -split method doesn't work for me but $Result.Split("`r`n") does work?

Comment: Your line endings may be \`r or \`n vs. \`r\`n

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution based on [RegexMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7#options), which is the default behavior of split.
This will work with all types of line endings:

- Windows (CR LF) `\r\n`
- old Macintosh (CR) `\r`
- Unix (LF) `\n`

```powershell
($result -split "\r?\n|\r") | Out-Host
```

If you want to get rid of consecutive line breaks you can use:

```powershell
($result -split "[\r\n]+") | Out-Host
```

Answer (score 2):

The safest system-agnostic way would be to use the built in environment property:

```
$result -split [Environment]::NewLine | % { Write-Host $_ }
```

Answer (score -1):

The safest? I don't think so.

```powershell
$result -split [Environment]::NewLine | % { Write-Host $_ }
# Doesn't work in cross-plataform
```

```powershell
# URI from a UNIX plataform BUT script runing in a WINDOWS plafatorm
$result = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI).Content 
$result -split [Environment]::NewLine | % { Write-Host $_ } # Doesn't work
$result -split "\r?\n|\r" | % { Write-Host $_ }             # Works
```